# How to prevent NuGet version drift in a big monolithic (sigh :-() application (multiple solutions, many projects in each)?

Tags: nuget

We are building all the solutions to a shared bin directory. Having different projects reference different versions of the same dependency is not healthy for our build.

So, we consolidated the dependencies - great. But now the versions start to drift again. We do not want to consolidate them manually every now and then - we want to prevent the drift completely.

Why we do not want to use Paket? The main reason is that it seems we would lose the ability to migrate the NuGet package dependencies to the new PackageReference items in the projects. So, currently we have package.config files, but we plan to replace them with the respective PackageReferences. That means we will use internal NuGet support by msbuild, which seems to leave no place for Paket.

Now, I assume we are not unique in this world and others have the same problem as we are. How do you solve it?

**EDIT 1**

We have our internal NuGet repo, but we use it for dependencies which do not have organic representation in Nuget.org and for sharing our own internal packages.

One approach is to consume only from the internal NuGet repository. This has challenges, like:

1. Who uploads the dependencies there? Developers? But then how to make sure they do not upload different versions of the same dependency? Dedicated people? Then they become a bottleneck.
2. Small thing, but we need to block commits to the central NuGet.config
3. Uploading a dependency to the internal NuGet repo is not immediate. You cannot just download it from NuGet.org and upload to the internal one, because that would miss any transitive dependencies. So, a process should be built around it.

It is all possible, but I am reluctant to go down that route ... Must be a better way.

**EDIT 2**

While we do plan to migrate to PackageReference, it will take time. And unfortunately as long as we have Silverlight (another year, at least) a whole bunch of projects in the dedicated Silverlight solution (80+) will not be migrated to PackageReference, because by doing so it becomes impossible to debug the code with VS 2015.

Next, suppose we do migrate ALL the projects and then externalize all the PackageReference items to a single targets file imported by all the projects. This is feasible when using a shared bin directory as we plan to do. But when inspected in VS 2017 this setup communicates a wrongful picture that every single project depends on the entire set of NuGet dependencies.
I would rather avoid this.

Comment: Have you thought of creating a custom repository for you own use that you could update as you needed so that your projects point to the custom repo?  You would then control updates as needed.  We kind of have that same problem.  We found that having a custom repo helped to minimize the problem.  Not completely eradicate as of yet... still exploring.

Comment: Do you mean a custom NuGet feed?   That is an interesting idea, which could prove useful.

Comment: @tster - Yes.  creating a custom repository can really help keep control over version creep and drift at least for us.

Comment: See **EDIT 1**.

Comment: about your last comment in edit 2, I don't suggest putting your `PackageReference`s in an external file and making all your projects have the same dependencies. Instead, your individual `csproj` files have a `<PackageReferene Include="packageid" Version="$(SomeMSBuildProperty) />`, and you keep the value of `SomeMSBuildProperty` in a single/central file. That way when you want to change versions, you edit one file and all references update to the same version, but individual projects still choose which packages they depend on.

Answer (score 1):

Once you move to PackageReference, you can take advantage of MSBuild. For example, you can have [a MSBuild file that contains all your dependency versions](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/f5ae3ee63d632cf2dead1c5e01ab7b2dd435fd79/build/config.props#L27-L34). It could be a file that you need to `<Import ... />` in all your `csproj` files, or you could use [`Directory.Build.props`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets). Finally, in each of your projects, [change the version number in any `<PackageReference` to a MSBuild variable that uses the property you previously defined](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/175cc816415e7a395c24318b1a593126afcb362a/build/test.targets#L14-L20). Most of Microsoft's open source repositories use this technique, with minor variations about file names and whether it's imported automatically with `Directory.Build.props`, or an explicit `<Import ... />`.

While you can still use the Package Manager UI in Visual Studio to check for updates, you won't be able to update the package versions with it (at least, it won't preserve how and where the versions are defined). However, just make sure your MSBuild file that defines the versions is in your solution, so you can trivially open the file in Solution Explorer and then type the new version number in. Adding new package references is slightly more effort, but it's generally not done often, and it's still very easy with SDK-style projects, since Visual Studio lets you edit the csproj while the project is still loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't accept the other solution, maybe you could take a look at [paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/)

It's a package manager for dotnet than (among other feature) holds solution wide dependency lock file. It is very customizable, and while it solves LOTS of problems, as any tool, creates some new ones. In my experience, the new ones are far less infuriating :)

Comment: We ended up by writing a tool that runs before build and inspects the dependencies of all the projects across all the solutions ensuring they are all the same.